# How to get all seperate all equal pairs from a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python program to find all equal pairs in a list. So if there is a single repeat of an element in a list it would be added to the list.

[2,2,2,2,2] would become [2,2]

[8,8,8,2] would become [8]

[8,16,16,8] would become [8,16]

[2,0,2,4] would become [2]

[0,0,2,2] would become [0,2]

So far i have tried nesting for loops.

```
def pairfinder(newlist):
pairlist = []
for idx in range(len(newlist)):
    for jdx in range(idx+1,len(newlist)):
        if newlist[idx] == newlist[jdx]:
            pairlist.append(newlist[idx])
            break
return pairlist
```

This gives me the correct answer on some cases.. but not all

Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: So you want the count modulus 2 of each number where the count is greater than 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: it is not clear yet how you want this to work ... ait seems like the last list should result in an empty list to me ...

Comment: why does the first example return `[2,2]` instead of simply `[2]`?

Comment: The goal is to find all pairs in a list. For example [0,1,2,1] would give [1] because there is 2 ones and 1 of everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print [a for a,b in zip(my_list[::2],my_list[1::2]) if a == b]
```

you may need to sort `my_list` first ...

```
my_list = sorted(my_list)
print [a for a,b in zip(my_list[::2],my_list[1::2]) if a == b]
```

Im not at all sure this solves your issue.

```
def do_this_weird_thing(a_list):
    from itertools import groupby
    for grp,item in groupby(sorted(a_list)):
        item = list(item)
        yield [grp] * (len(item)//2)

from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable(do_this_weird_thing([2,0,2,4])))
```